# if $\beta < \gamma$, then $\alpha + \beta < \alpha + \gamma$ for ordinals $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I'm trying to prove if $\beta < \gamma$, then $\alpha + \beta < \alpha + \gamma$ for ordinals $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ via induction on $\gamma$.

First, if $\gamma = 0$, the statements vacuously holds because there are no such $\beta < \gamma$.

I run into a problem for the case $\gamma = \gamma' + 1$, the successor case. The IH would be that for $\beta' < \gamma'$, $\alpha + \beta' < \alpha + r'$. Now, I want to show for $\beta < \gamma, \alpha + \beta < \alpha + \gamma$. How do I quantify over $\beta$ in this case?

Any advice would be appreciated!

This post [Prove that if $\alpha<\beta$ then $\gamma + \alpha < \gamma + \beta$ for ordinals.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3784549/prove-that-if-alpha-beta-then-gamma-alpha-gamma-beta-for-ordinal?rq=1) asks the same question, but it doesn't address the successor case.

Comment: Ordinal addition is associative. If $b<c$ then $c\ge b+1$ so $a+c\ge a+(b+1)=(a+b)+1>(a+b_.$

Comment: If $\xi<\zeta+1$, then $\xi\leq\zeta$, so $\xi<\zeta$ or $\xi=\zeta$. So we have two cases, both of which are pretty straightforward to check.

Comment: @markvs Why would that be true, if the statement I'm trying to prove holds for all $\beta' < \gamma'$?

Comment: I have already forgotten why I posted the comment. I'll delete it.